# Configure IIS and OpenSRS domain

Tags: iis, domain, configuration

I've got a Windows VPS and purchased domain from opensrs.net, for example xyz.me
What should I do to connect them? So I typed into browser xyz.me and then my request is passed to my Windows VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should figure out what the IP address is for your VPS. Then, you should configure DNS for your newly acquired domain name. In the DNS for your domain name, you will probably want to add an A record for the domain name itself, and an A (or possibly a CNAME) record for 'www'.

How your domain name is configured depends on where your DNS is hosted. If you host your DNS with OpenSRS, you'll find the DNS Configuration Guide (PDF) on the [Control Panels](http://www.opensrs.com/site/resources/documentation/controlpanels) help page.

Note that you can have multiple virtual hosts (websites) on a single VPS — I'm assuming you have uploaded a default website to your VPS.